# Jump time of a previsible process is previsible?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Here is my question:

In our setups, the filtration satisfies the usual condition. $V$ is an increasing process with only jumps (between the jumps it is flat). We also know that $V$ is right continuous and previsible. Now, define a stopping time:
$$\tau:= \inf\{t> 0|V_t\neq V_{t-}\}.$$
My question is whether $\tau$ is a previsible stopping time, i.e. there exists a sequence of stopping time $\tau_n$ such that $\tau_n<\tau$ and $\tau_n\uparrow \tau$. Thanks !

Comment: @ user129670 : Hi this is an excellent and very natural question to ask, I have looked through a few references and have not found any results in this direction. The only thing I have found which is close in spirit is that the jumps of such a process are included in the union  of the disjoint "graph" of a sequence of predictable times (not necessarily the jumps times !!!). The result if true doesn't seem trivial to prove. Best regards